# How can i delete fragments from ram

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using more than one fragment.  I destroy them with 'GetSupportFragmentManager ().PopBackStack ();' but if I call the same fragments again in my ram usage, I see an increase, the native part is constantly increasing. There are no pictures in the trailers, there are buttons, I do not get an error, but how much will this ram use increase? Isn't there a way to completely destroy background fragments? Or is it normal for this to happen?

Comment: There is no way manually delete the fragments. Make sure your fragment does not leak anything. It will be garbage collected when needed

Comment: Make sure your fragment does not leak anything. this mean any background work or image ?

Comment: If you are using adapter in Fragment and that adapter is a member in Fragment then you should detach that adapter onDestroyView() by calling listview.adapter = null